# Error:13 - Permission Denied android studio

Tags: linux, gradle

I have 
[image: here]

this problem and I set `chmod -x gradlew` file
and change jcenter() to mavencentral()
and use cisco anyconnect vpn for im in asia and filtering 
please help and offer me solotion

Answer (score 0):

change sdk platform to java sdk 1.8 latest version

Answer (score 0):

I too ran into the same problem today and i found the solution as:

1) Open the installation location of the android studio using the the files.Then right click on the file **select-> Open in terminal**

2)Then change the ownership by su command

```
zeus@debian:~/Downloads$ su
Password: 
root@debian:/home/zeus/Downloads# chown zeus android-studio
```

3)Then open the file explorer window and right click the folder and  **select -> Properties**

4)Under the permissions tab,click on **"Change permissions for Enclosed files"**
[Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruP1C.png)

5)Change the file options to "**Read and Write**" for group and others.

6)Change the folder options to "**Create and Delete files**" for group and others.

7)Restart the application.

That solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after viewing the log file, Android studio couldn't get the permission to run the jre that came embedded with it. Switching to the systems jdk solved it.

Here are the steps:

1. Go to **File > Project Structure**
2. Uncheck the option that says **Use embedded JDK**
3. Choose the location of your jdk installation in the system. In my case, it was located at */usr/lib/jvm*

Answer (score 0):

This is issue of jdk. Check your jdk location by typing `which java` in linux and just `search jsk` location in windows and insert that location in Android Studio `File > Project Structure`.     embeded jdk (uncheck the checkbox above it first).